# Reference inside hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
test = {
  :key1 => "Test",
  :key2 => "Test2",
  :key3 => REF TO KEY1
}
```

Is it possible to let `key3` refer to the `key1` value?

Comment: No, this is not possible in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not recommended and my guess is that [there is a better way to solve whatever larger problem you are attempting to solve with this technique](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

But one way you could do this is by creating a `Hash` whose [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) returns the value of `:key1` if it is passed `:key3`.

```
> test = Hash.new { |h,k| k == :key3 ? h[:key1] : nil }
> test[:key1] = "Test"
> puts test[:key3]
Test
```

And this acts as a reference as can be seen if we modify the value of `:key1`

```
> test[:key1] = "Test2"
> puts test[:key3]
Test2
```

Comment: Why are you using different expressions `test.update({:key1=>"Test"})`, and then `test[:key1] = "Test2`? Don't you just want to do similar things twice with different values?

Comment: @sawa no reason, I see how that is confusing, I think I was trying a few different things to see if they made a difference. I will edit it so that it consistent and clearer. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Another thing to point out is that the OP wanted `:key3`'s value to follow `:key1`'s. But your code let `:key2`'s value follow `:key1`'s. Perhaps that is the reason your answer has not gained much upvotes despite the idea being correct.

Comment: @sawa I'm always in favour of making my examples as minimal as possible so as not to cause additional confusion (my last edit notwithstanding). But if you think that it's clearer...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easily possible. The expression for the value can be any arbitrary Ruby expression, including of course accessing a value from a `Hash`:

```
test = {
  :key1 => "Test",
  :key2 => "Test2",
}

test[:key3] = test[:key1]
```

Comment: Although the OP has not stated clear, my guess is that the OP wants `:key3`'s value to dynamically follow that of `:key1` (even if that has changed at some point).